# Task Cancellation with multiple sources

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library, cancellation

I currently have an application where I create a series of Tasks that execute one after the other, with a cancellation source that can interrupt execution between Tasks (i.e. at safe termination points.)  I currently use this cancellation source only when the managing class is Disposed, as a way to cleanly and quickly abort execution.

I now have a use case where I'd like to create an automatic timeout to cancel the Task sequence, in case the operator doesn't respond in a timely manner (some of the Tasks wait on operator interaction with a physical mechanism.)  At the same time, I still need to support cancellation if the managing class is Disposed.  I found [CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642265.aspx), which sounds like what I need, but I have a few concerns:

1. Multiple Task-series can be executed in parallel, so I need to create a new CancellationTokenSource for timeout cancellation and an associated linked source for each Task-series that I begin.  CancellationTokenSource implements IDisposable, which means that I need to persist both cancellation sources and Dispose them when the last Task completes or when any of the sub-Tasks is Cancelled or Faulted.  This seems rather awkward, even with the helpful magic of anonymous method closures (still have these cancellation sources being passed around.)
2. I also need to protect against the condition where the cancellation sources are Disposed before the timer expires (so I don't Cancel a Disposed source.)  This is a potential race condition, so I need to add appropriate locking.  This also seems awkward, adds significant complexity (future maintenance cost) and makes unit testing more challenging (race conditions are tricky to reliably induce.)

Am I heading down the correct path here or is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The core issue in your question seems to be relating to calling `Dispose()` on your `Task` and/or `CancellationTokenSource` objects.  In this case, I would recommend just *not* calling `Dispose` on these, which should dramatically simplify your design.

As justification I'll refer you to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/7b3a42e5-4ebf-405a-8ee6-bcd2f0214f85).  In particular, Stephen Toub (the PM in charge of Task) suggests that you should:

> dispose aggressively *if* it's easy and correct to do based on the structure of your code.  If you start having to do strange gyrations in order to Dispose (or in the case of Tasks, use additional synchronization to ensure it's safe to dispose, since Dispose may only be used once a task has completed), it's likely better to rely on finalization to take care of things.

This sounds like the exact situation he's describing at the end - you're trying to do strange gyrations in order to call `Dispose()` on these objects.

Comment: I've had it drilled into me rather strongly that I should always call Dispose on IDisposable objects, so I hesitate to do this, even with Stephen Toub's blessing.  In fact, the MSDN documentation for `CancellationTokenSource.Dispose()` specifically states that you should always call Dispose(); this is probably just catch-all verbiage, but this suggests there is no contractual obligation for the .NET team to leave Dispose() 'optional' for this class.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321505.aspx

Comment: @Dan: I know - but, remember, any properly implemented `IDisposable` object will get "cleaned up" by the finalizer if you don't call `Dispose()` on it.  I feel that you should always *try to call* `Dispose()` on any `IDisposable` object, but, in some cases, you're making your life far worse than just leaving it up to the finalizer.  The TPL is one of those areas where things get fuzzy - it's very often (IMO) much better to not `Dispose()` TPL objects, because the work required in doing them is far more likely to introduce maintenance problems and bugs.

Comment: I definitely see your point (from the practical, get-the-job-done perspective) and that's probably what I'll end up doing, but these 'lesser of two evils' situations irk me.  At this point, however, the objection is more philosophical than technical, which no amount of engineering can possibly hope to resolve.

Comment: @Dan: I know what you mean - It bugs me to not dispose something "on purpose" - but at the end of the day, it's the far lesser of the evils....